# Which is lighter on resources - Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, performance

Which is lighter on resources - Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04?

I'd like to run a linux VM on my PC, I prefer having the most updated linux on the one hand, on the other hand, my resources are limited.

EDIT:
I need a GUI, but I can do with some lightweight GUI, as XFCE. So I think of installing a headless VM, with xfce, and access the GUI through VNC.

Comment: Depends on how you configure it. Server or Desktop? Headless or with a GUI? Basic services or all standard services? Or is this just for the basic core kernal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the resources required are by the desktop environment GUI. I would use 16.10 or 16.04, with Xubuntu or Lubuntu, as they are much lighter than Unity that comes stock.

Answer (score 1):

As most cases, the latest stable version is the most optimised and efficient in terms of performance. In saying that, the desktop environments do hog a considerable amount of resources (for low-powered machines), but XFCE shouldn't take away too much performance.

Even without a GUI, I'd say either 16.xx version. With a GUI doesn't really change much either - either 16.xx version.

At the end of the day, it's like buying computer components. X component is older than Y component. Which one is faster? Generally, Y component will be faster (assuming they're both continuations of the same product line)

Comment: Windows XP still boots faster than any new Win versions ;)

Comment: Yes, well... Windows is an exception to that rule ;)